# How did we got the answer of the given sum

Tags: calculus, summation

How did we got this answer from this sum:

> Sum = n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + n-(a-1) + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 
>   n-(b-1) 
>    = **n(a+b-1) - (a-1)a/2 - (b-1)b/2**

Can you explain with steps?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a nice little trick:
Let's split it into two sums:
\begin{equation}
S_1=n+(n-1)+\ldots+n-(a-1),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
S_2=(n-1)+(n-2)+\ldots + n-(b-1).
\end{equation}
Now you write down $S_1$ two times, once from front to back and once the other way around:
\begin{equation}
S_1=n+(n-1)+\ldots+n-(a-1),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
S_1=n-(a-1)+\ldots + (n-1)+n.
\end{equation}
We can sum them to get:
\begin{equation}
2S_1=2n-(a-1)+\ldots +2n-(a-1) + 2n-(a-1).
\end{equation}
So, we get the same term for $a$ times. We thus get
\begin{equation}
2S_1=a(2n-(a-1))=2an-a(a-1) \Rightarrow S_1=an-a(a-1)/2.
\end{equation}
In the same way for $S_2$ we get
\begin{equation}
2S_2=(b-1)(2n-b) \Rightarrow S_2=(b-1)(2n-b)/2.
\end{equation}
In total we get the answer:
\begin{equation}
S=an-a(a-1)/2+(b-1)(2n-b)/2=n(a+b-1) - (a-1)a/2 - (b-1)b/2
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks .... I am wondering how did we sum up S1+S1, can you explain it more?

Comment: You do it term by term. The first term of the first S1 is n.  The first term of the backwards term is n-(a-1), these terms sum up to 2n-(a-1). The next term is one lower in the first S1 en one higher in the backwards S1, so the sum of the terms will also give 2n-(a-1)